# How to get the top 10 students in the class using Python dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with student-name and marks

```
dict1 = {'name1': 34, 'name2':45, 'name3': 98, 'name4':34, 'name5': 66}
```

I want to get the top 10 student names along with their marks from the above dict.

**Result:**

```
name3 98
name5 66
name2 45
name1 34
name4 34
```

In case of multiple keys for same values, keys must be in alphabetical order (Ex: name1 and name4 are in alphabetical order for same value 34)

How to get it done ?

Comment: Don't name your variable `dict`; it shadows the built-in type.

Comment: I was going to say give them pizza and beer :)

Comment: -1 for not making an attempt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Naive solution

You can write this in plain python:

```
>>> names = {'name1': 34, 'name2':45, 'name3': 98, 'name4':34, 'name5': 66}
>>> sorted_names = sorted(names.iteritems(), key=lambda (k, v): (-v, k))[:10]
>>> sorted_names
[('name3', 98), ('name5', 66), ('name2', 45), ('name1', 34), ('name4', 34)]
```

[`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) takes a key for sorting as the comparison

Then just print them as you wish:

```
>>> for name, score in sorted_names:
...     print name, score
...
name3 98
name5 66
name2 45
name1 34
name4 34
```

Or just do it all at once:

```
>>> for name, score in sorted(names.iteritems(), key=lambda (k, v): (-v, k))[:10]:
...     print name, score
...
name3 98
name5 66
name2 45
name1 34
name4 34
```

### Inspired by [@Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters)' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16571448/1549047)

Using [`heapq`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html) and in particular [`heapq.nsmallest`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.nsmallest) you can have a much more elegant solution:

```
>>> from heapq import nsmallest
>>> for name, score in nsmallest(10, names.iteritems(), key=lambda (k, v): (-v, k)):
...     print name, score
...
name3 98
name5 66
name2 45
name1 34
name4 34
```

What I like about this solution is that [`nsmallest`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.nsmallest) could be implemented intelligently.  It could be something like a lazy implementation like is described in this answer to [Lazy Evaluation and Time Complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12057921/1549047).  And so, you'd only do the minimum amount of work.  Whereas the naive solution would **have** to sort the entire iterable before getting the first 10.

Comment: You can use `reverse=True` instead of negating the score.

Comment: joneshf,  everything looks fine. But the last two names should be in the alphabetical order, i.e. name1 34 and name4 34   but not name4 34 and name1 34

Comment: @Kranti updated, you should also update your question to include that condition aswell.  Unfortunately that gets rid of the reverse=True, but whatever.

Comment: Nice work there getting `heapq` to return names in sorted order for equal scores!

Answer (score 11):

Use [`heapq.nlargest()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest):

```
from heapq import nlargest
from operator import itemgetter

for name, score in nlargest(10, dictionary.iteritems(), key=itemgetter(1)):
    print name, score
```

Demo:

```
>>> for name, score in nlargest(10, dictionary.iteritems(), key=itemgetter(1)):
...     print name, score
... 
name3 98
name5 66
name2 45
name4 34
name1 34
```

Note that because your sample dictionary is *smaller* than the top `n` you want, you could just as well have used `sorted()`:

```
for name, score in sorted(dictionary.iteritems(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True):
    print name, score
```

but for any top `n` where `n` is smaller than `len(dictionary)` `heapq` is the better choice.

Alternatively, use a `collections.Counter()` object, it has a `.most_common()` method that gives you exactly that; the highest `n` scoring elements in the counter:

```
>>> scores = Counter(dictionary)
>>> scores
Counter({'name3': 98, 'name5': 66, 'name2': 45, 'name4': 34, 'name1': 34})
>>> scores.most_common(3)
[('name3', 98), ('name5', 66), ('name2', 45)]
```