# Shell script to output the largest

Tags: bash, shell, bin

How to write a script which will receive a list of parameters and output the number that is the largest. If no parameters are supplied, output an error message.

I wrote the following code to check if no parameters are supplied, output an error message.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$#" -eq  "0" ]
then
  echo "No arugments supplied"
else
  echo "$# Parameter"
```

But I dont know how to continue...

Comment: You could use `sort` and `head` to sort the list in descending order and grab the first item, have you tried that?

Comment: What is different if it's homework or not? Who love homework :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sort -n (numeric) and -r (reverse) and then just pick the first line of the output -- like

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$#" -eq  "0" ]
then
  echo "No arugments supplied"
else
  echo "$# Parameter"
  for i in $*; do echo ${i}; done | sort -nr | head -1
fi
```

Now the only problem you are facing is when the the input (the arguments) are not numbers -- but you didn't say anything about what should happen then.

Comment: n * log n complexity. You can do better.

Comment: @Jubobs Complexity depends on the algorithm `sort` uses. It could be O(1).

Comment: @melpomene A comparison-based sorting algorithm cannot be faster than n * log n.

Comment: @Jubobs We're only inspecting a fixed prefix of the result, so it doesn't have to sort the whole list.

Comment: @melpomene I don't understand your last comment. If the OP wants to find the maximum of all command-line arguments, s/he needs to inspect all n of them. This is what you do in your [own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33055668/2541573).

Comment: @Jubobs Yes, by passing them to sort. But we don't inspect all of sort's result. (Btw, my "could be O(1)" above is a typo; I meant "could be O(n)".) See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12057658/lazy-evaluation-and-time-complexity.

Comment: @melpomene Interesting link (thanks), but I doubt any implementation of POSIX  `sort` relies on lazy evaluation.

Comment: @Jubobs The laziness is implicit in the use of pipes (`|`): `head` will stop reading after the first line and exit, which will terminate `sort` with `SIGPIPE` if it tries to produce more output afterwards. It only depends on whether `sort` will output anything before it has finished sorting everything, which in turn depends on the algorithm it uses.

Comment: @Jubobs -- the "complexity" is actually low -- it is one line and not complex at all -- the efficiency (as in big-O notation) may not be the best, however nothing written in a shell script is expected to be the most efficient code -- when it comes to shell scripts simplicity should always win.

Comment: @melpomene Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Keep a current max. Loop over the input, updating max if necessary. At the end you'll have the global maximum.

Untested:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 NUMBERS" >&2
    exit 1;
fi

max="$1"
shift
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
    if [ "$1" -gt "$max" ]; then
        max="$1"
    fi
    shift
done

echo "$max"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pseudocode you could implement:

- save the first param in a variable called `max`
- loop over the params

  - if the param is greater than `max`, update `max`
- print `max`

Here's an example loop that prints all parameters:

```
for num; do
    echo $num
done
```

And here's an example of comparing values:

```
if (( num > max )); then
    echo $num is greater than $max
fi
```

This should be more than enough help to complete your homework.

---

Well since others have already gave you the actual solution, here's mine too:

```
#!/bin/bash

if (( $# == 0 )); then
    echo "No arugments supplied"
    exit 1
fi

max=$1
for num; do
    if (( num > max )); then
        max=$num
    fi
done

echo $max
```