# How to find a second largest number in a list in Haskell?

Tags: sorting, haskell

The question is like this:

Write a function that takes an integer list and returns its length and the
second largest integer in the list.

I can solve this with two functions but is there any solution that use only one function to do it?

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: What's your definition of "1 function" vs "2 functions"? You can put the second one in a `where` clause of the first one, then it's only one function :)

Comment: The general solution for finding the top k items (and therefore the kth largest item) in a single pass uses a priority queue, so you always know the top k so far at every step through the iteration. There's a blog post [here](http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=122). For very small k, a priority queue might be overkill in performance terms, but it's probably easiest to stick with it - don't optimise prematurely IOW. I'm sure there's a suitable priority queue in the Haskell library somewhere.

Comment: @Steve314 I think that is unnecessary in Haskell, as the lazy evaluation means that using something like take k (sort xs) should be efficient.

Comment: @Steve314 With GHC's implementation of `sort`, the `take k (sort xs)` trick is asymptotically optimal.

Comment: @Steve314 This is a win of laziness over strictness, not functional over imperative. See also [my answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868507/non-trivial-lazy-evaluation/7868790#7868790) which tries to explain the core advantage of laziness.

Comment: @Daniel Wagner - I'm not scoring very well today, eh! OK, I see the point.

Comment: What should it return for a list of just one element?

Answer (score 4):

Don't make it complicated.

```
f xs = (sort xs !! 1, length xs)
```

If you choose to make it complicated, [make it complicated in the right way](http://squing.blogspot.com/2008/11/beautiful-folding.html).

Comment: I interpreted 'second largest integer' to be in terms of magnitude.  I.e. in `[1,1,2,3,3]`, we'd want 2.  (psst, your sort order is backwards ;) ).

Comment: As Daniel hasn't fixed this yet - to change the `sort` order, use [`sortBy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v:sortBy). Or, in the spirit of the existing code, use something like `reverse . sort $ xs !! 1`. Or, as `length xs` is being evaluated anyway, use `sort xs !! (length xs - 2)`.

Answer (score 3):

**Edited to use [@ThomasM.DuBuisson's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/216164/thomas-m-dubuisson) suggestion**

You can solve this the same way that you could finding the max: using a fold.  Max can be pretty trivially implemented with

```hs
mymaximum :: Ord a => [a] -> a
mymaximum xs = foldl searcher (head xs) xs
    where
        searcher :: Ord a => a -> a -> a
        searcher a b
            | a > b     = a
            | otherwise = b
```

So we can implement it similarly by just keeping up with the two largest values (notice that we have to "seed" the fold with a tuple as well):

```hs
nextmaximum :: Ord a => [a] -> a
nextmaximum xs = fst $ foldl searcher (h, h) xs
    where
        h = head xs
        searcher :: (Ord a) => (a, a) -> a -> (a, a)
        searcher (s, f) x = (min f (max s x), max f x)
```

Comment: `searcher (s,f) x = (min f (max s x), max f x)`

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson Good suggestion, it'd be faster and it's much simpler.

Comment: @zip Notice this solution is partial - it will raise an exception if passed a null list.  It is easy enough to change this behavior (pattern match the argument to `nextmaximum` and handle the special case), but it isn't clear what you'd like done in this case.

Comment: We can simplify, `foldr searcher (head xs) xs == foldr1 searcher xs`

Answer (score 2):

You can just compose individual functions together.  This is neither efficient nor robust, but it's sure easy to write:

```
f xs = maximum . filter (< maximum xs) $ xs
```

Answer (score 1):

```
head . (!!1) . group . sortBy (flip compare) $ [1,1,2,3,4,4,4,5,5,6,6,6,6]
5
```