# Generate First n Primes (Haskell)

Tags: list, haskell, primes, lazy-evaluation, counting

I have this function:

```
generatePrimes :: Integral a => a -> [a]
generatePrimes n = [i | i <- [2..], isPrime i]
```

I am trying to get the first *n* primes. I know that I can call the function in `main` by using the `take` function (and get the first *n* elements of the list), but I want to be able to have the function stop when it reaches *n* primes (inside the function), so that when it is called in `main` such as:

```
generatePrimes 8
```

it will display a list with only the first 8 primes.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying about "stopping inside the function". You could simply define `generatePrimes n = take n allPrimes`. Due to lazyness this will stop after finding `n` primes, there's no real overhead. The result *is* a list of the first `n` primes. Please clarify that requirement.

Comment: `take` will 'stop' once it has pulled the desired number of elements from the list. Why doesn't that fit your requirements?

Comment: Explicitly testing each number for being prime isn't a very good way to generate a list of primes. For one thing, the tests on the even numbers after 2 are pointless.

Comment: Somewhat related, for those of you who haven't already read it, is this wonderful Functional Pearl: https://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf

Answer (score 5):

The answer to your question as stated is to simply move `take` into the definition of `generatePrimes`, thus:

```
generatePrimes :: Integral a => Int -> [a]
generatePrimes n = take n [i | i <- [2..], isPrime i]
```

If it is important that you keep the exact same type signature as in the question, you may use the more polymorphic version of `take` available in `Data.List`:

```
import Data.List
generatePrimes :: Integral a => a -> [a]
generatePrimes n = genericTake n [i | i <- [2..], isPrime i]
```

(Indeed, this implementation has the even more general type `generatePrimes :: (Integral a, Integral i) => i -> [a]`.)

However, this is [anti-modular in the presence of lazy evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7868790/791604); you should leave control over how much of the list is consumed to the consumer rather than the producer.

Comment: Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `a'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for generatePrimes :: Integral a => a -> [a]
          at Primes.hs:53:19
    Relevant bindings include
      n :: a (bound at Primes.hs:54:16)
      generatePrimes :: a -> [a] (bound at Primes.hs:54:1)
    In the first argument of `take', namely `n'
    In the expression: take n [i | i <- [2 .. ], isPrime i]

Comment: @user3247014 Ah. You may use `Data.List.genericTake` instead of `take`, or change the type signature. I will update my answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Another implementation of printing the first **n** prime numbers can be done with pattern matching. Given as input a list that its range is from **2** to **n**, the function *isPrime* returns all the values that are prime numbers.

```
isPrime [p] = if null ([x | x <- [2.. p - 1], mod p x == 0])
              then show p 
              else ""

isPrime (p:ps) = if null ([x | x <- [2.. p - 1], mod p x == 0])
                 then show p ++ ", " ++ isPrime(ps)
                 else "" ++ isPrime(ps)
```

In order to execute the first **n** numbers, we can use ranges and just type: `isPrime[2..n]`. We consider number 2 to be the first prime number.