# How to provide a specific range of inputs to a function in Haskell

Tags: haskell, primes

I'm new to Haskell and I'm wondering if it's possible to provide a range of the first 51 prime numbers as input rather than typing the prime numbers, see line 2 ?

If so, please modify the code and post the solution.

```
  1 perfect_nums n = (2^(n-1)) * ((2^n)-1)
  2 fperfect_nums = [perfect_nums x | x <- [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97,101,103,107,109,113,127,131,137,139,149,151,157,163,167,173,179,181,191,193,197,199,211,223,227,229,233]]
  3 main = print $ fperfect_nums
```

Comment: You can create a function to [generate the first n prime numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35754806/generate-first-n-primes-haskell) and use those to populate your list.

Comment: There are various ways in Haskell to produce the list of prime numbers, as detailed in the [relevant page of the Haskell wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Prime_numbers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function to generate primes or use a library. I like to use [`arithmoi`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/arithmoi) for this purpose:

```
import Math.NumberTheory.Primes (nextPrime, unPrime)

perfectNums :: Integer -> Integer
perfectNums n = (2^(n-1)) * ((2^n)-1)

fperfectNums :: [Integer]
fperfectNums = [perfectNums (unPrime x) | x <- take 51 [nextPrime 0 ..]]

main :: IO ()
main = print fperfectNums
```

Comment: I'm getting the error shown below. I import it the same way. Is there any other module that needs to be imported?

Could not find module ‘Math.NumberTheory.Primes’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
1 | import Math.NumberTheory.Primes (nextPrime, unPrime)
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.

Comment: @Tom: you need to install the `arithmoi` package first.

Answer (score 0):

Well you already have

```
fperfect_nums = [perfect_nums x | x <- [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97,101,103,107,109,113,127,131,137,139,149,151,157,163,167,173,179,181,191,193,197,199,211,223,227,229,233]]
              = [perfect_nums x | x <- primes51]

primes51 = [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97,101,103,107,109,113,127,131,137,139,149,151,157,163,167,173,179,181,191,193,197,199,211,223,227,229,233]
```

and that is

```
 = take 51 $ [2 .. 288] `minus`
      [4, 6 .. 288] `minus`       -- all the multiples of 2 in the range
       [9, 12 .. 288] `minus`      -- all the multiples of 3 in the range
        [25, 30 .. 288] `minus`     -- and of 5, 7, 11, ...
         [49, 56 .. 288] `minus`     -- until we see that
          [121, 132 .. 288] `minus`   -- 13*13 = 169  whereas
           [169, 182 .. 288]           -- 17*17 = 289   which is above 233

 = take 51 $ [2 .. 288] `minus`
      (let {p=2} in [p*p, p*p+p .. 288]) `minus` 
       (let {p=3} in [p*p, p*p+p .. 288]) `minus` 
        (let {p=5} in [p*p, p*p+p .. 288]) `minus` 
         (let {p=7} in [p*p, p*p+p .. 288]) `minus` 
          (let {p=11} in [p*p, p*p+p .. 288]) `minus`  -- 13*13 = 169
           (let {p=13} in [p*p, p*p+p .. 288])          -- 17*17 = 289

 = take 51 $ [2 .. 288] `minus` (
      (let {p=2} in [p*p, p*p+p .. 288]) `union` 
       (let {p=3} in [p*p, p*p+p .. 288]) `union` 
        (let {p=5} in [p*p, p*p+p .. 288]) `union` 
         (let {p=7} in [p*p, p*p+p .. 288]) `union` 
          (let {p=11} in [p*p, p*p+p .. 288]) `union`
           (let {p=13} in [p*p, p*p+p .. 288]) )

 = take 51 $ [2 .. 288] `minus` ( foldr1 union
      [[p*p, p*p+p .. 288] | p <- [2,3,5,7,11,13]] )

minus xs ys = [ x | x <- xs, not (elem x ys)]
union xs ys = xs ++ ys
```

So yes, it is indeed possible to provide a range of the first 51 prime numbers as input rather than typing all the 51 prime numbers yourself. You just need to type the first 6 prime numbers yourself, for that.

And you actually have 61 of them there,

```
primesTo288 = 2 : [3 .. 288] `minus` ( foldr1 union
      [[p*p, p*p+p .. 288] | p <- [2,3,5,7,11,13]] )
 = 2 : 3 : [5,7 .. 288] `minus` ( foldr1 union
      [[p*p, p*p+2*p .. 288] | p <- [3,5,7,11,13]] )
```

Now to make it unbounded ....