# Haskell IO, cassava documentation, Data.csv

Tags: csv, haskell, io, decode, read.csv

I am trying to learn IO in Haskell and I found it very confusing. Went through the [`cassava` documentation on hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cassava) under *"use [`decodeByName`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cassava/docs/Data-Csv.html#v:decodeByName):"*

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Control.Applicative
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL
import Data.Csv
import qualified Data.Vector as V

data Person = Person
    { name   :: !String
    , salary :: !Int
    }

instance FromNamedRecord Person where
    parseNamedRecord r = Person <$> r .: "name" <*> r .: "salary"

main :: IO ()
main = do
    csvData <- BL.readFile "salaries.csv"
    case decodeByName csvData of
        Left err -> putStrLn err
        Right (_, v) -> V.forM_ v $ \ p ->
            putStrLn $ name p ++ " earns " ++ show (salary p) ++ " dollars"
```

I have two questions here

1. In the declaration for `Person` against name they have used `!String` instead of `String`, why? I ran the same example with `String` and there was no difference in output. The tutorial on stack builders site also use the `!`. What am I missing here?
2. In the main function what does

   ```
           Right (_, v) -> V.forM_ v $ \ p ->
               putStrLn $ name p ++ " earns " ++ show (salary p) ++ " dollars"
   ```

   do?

I understand that `post $ \ p` is an anonymous function that puts a new string concatenating name from `p` and `salary` from `p` showing `salary` because it is an integer.

What does `p` stand for? Is it a tuple, a variable? Have they used `p` for the `Person` data structure?

What does the expression `Right (_, v) -> V.forM_ v`  mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`!` before a type is called a [`BangPattern`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/strict.html) and it causes the argument to be evaluated to weak head normal form when the data type is constructed. Informally, it decreases the amount of laziness which in some cases will improve performance.

`Right (_, v) -> V.forM_ v $ \p -> ...`
This part pattern matches on `v` which is a `Vector` of rows, in your case of type `Person`. `V.forM_` is a function of type `Monad m => Vector a -> (a -> m b) -> m ()` from the [`vector` package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.13.1.0/docs/Data-Vector.html#v:forM_). Essentially, it performs a monadic action for each element of the vector, in your case, an `IO` action of type `Person -> IO ()`. So `p` in this case, is an individual `Person`.

Comment: so the code will work slower if ! is not there.. but it is not an error .. correct? Is there a scenario when we know whether it is to be used or not ?

Comment: @cka as a rule of thumb, always use the `!`. There is a language extension which automatically does it. At the top of a file add `{#- LANGUAGE StrictData -#}`. Check [Kowainik](https://kowainik.github.io/posts/2019-02-06-style-guide#strictness) blog for more reference

Comment: I think I'd tweak that rule of thumb slightly: use `!` unless the field is recursive, i.e. contains a subterm of the same type as the one currently being defined. It is [very idiomatic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868507) to lazily produce recursive values and let the consumer choose which parts of the value to look at.